# The continuity of ordered eigenvalues of a matrix with function elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a matrix of $n\times n$ whose element is continous functiions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $A$ is an Hermitian matrix at every point of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means all its $n$ eigenvalues are real mumbers . Let $\lambda_{1}(x) \leqslant \ldots \leqslant \lambda_{n}(x)$ be the eigenvalues of  $A$

**My qustion is :Is $\lambda_i$ continous for arbitrary $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$?**

**clue:** In Chapter 9 of *Linear Algebra and Its Applications__Wiley-Interscience__Peter D. Lax*. It seems to be a standard result. But here I want to make sure.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: What when the Eigenvalues are not real ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you a lot! I have reedited my question by adding Hermitian condition on $A$. Now Is $\lambda_i$ continous ? Thank you again!

Comment: Isn't my answer enough ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Sorry, I cannot judge whether the cause of discontinuity has disappeared under hermitian assumption. Please excuse my ignorance. Thank you!

Comment: Do you understand the reason of my second sentence ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't really know the relationship between the roots of the equation and his coefficients. So I cannot have a good understand of your second sentence.

Comment: You don't need this to understand the second sentence, it is an elementary property.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So $\lambda_i$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, under the Hermitian condition, it is.

Comment: This is a worthwhile read:  https://cklixx.people.wm.edu/ELA-LiZhangMS4123.pdf  OP may be looking for Kato's theorem on page 4

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial has coefficients which are affine functions of the individual  matrix elements, hence this polynomial is a continuous function of all variables.

But the real roots in $\lambda$ can appear or disappear in pairs, causing discontinuities in the numbering.